# My stored procedure isn't working when called

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When I call this procedure from my `C#` code the procedure does not get executed.

I have two parameters - one is an output parameter and the other is an input parameter.

(Oracle SQL Developer)

`SQL` code:

```
    PROCEDURE manual_process(j_cursor OUT outputcursor, p_manual_date                         
    VARCHAR2)
    IS

    BEGIN
    OPEN j_cursor FOR
    SELECT i.*, TO_CHAR((i.maturity_date - 1), 'dd-MM-YYYY') 
    yesterday_date
    FROM ntb_rpa_int_code_summary i
    WHERE trunc(rec_mntn_date) = p_manual_date
    AND rec_status = 'A'
    AND process_status='N';
    END;
```

Visual Studio code(`C#`):

```
     OracleParameter[] param = { new OracleParameter("j_cursor", 
     OracleDbType.RefCursor), new OracleParameter("p_manual_date",OracleDbType.Varchar2)};

     param[0].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
     param[1].Value = reg_date;

     DataSet accountDs = dbObj.RunProcedureOracle("ntb_rpa_intrst_rate_code_chnge.manual_process", param, "accTbl");
```

Comment: Is it just this stored procedure that's not working? Do other stored procedures work?

Comment: Have you tried to execute storedprocedure in sql, is it working there?

Comment: the other procedures do work but not this one when called

Comment: this sql code do work in SQL Navigator but not on ORACLE sql developer

Comment: When you say *"doesn't work"* what do you actually mean? Do you get an Oracle error? An empty result set? A C# exception? Also, why are you passing your input data as a string rather than a DATE? From `trunc(rec_mntn_date)` I would guess you're **comparing** it to a DATE column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure does not compile

```
PROCEDURE manual_process(j_cursor OUT outputcursor, p_manual_date
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^

PLS-00201: identifier 'OUTPUTCURSOR' must be declared
```

This would compile:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE manual_process(j_cursor OUT sys_refcursor, p_manual_date                         
    VARCHAR2)
    IS

    BEGIN
    OPEN j_cursor FOR
    SELECT i.*, TO_CHAR((i.maturity_date - 1), 'dd-MM-YYYY') 
    yesterday_date
    FROM ntb_rpa_int_code_summary i
    WHERE trunc(rec_mntn_date) = p_manual_date
    AND rec_status = 'A'
    AND process_status='N';
    END;
```

Not sure if it works with your C# program, but I think it looks good.